# Selecting Solve results according to conditions

Tags: equation-solving

When using the Solve function I get four possible answers. How can I automatically get the option in which x and y are positive? Where to insert the conditions x>=0 and y>=0?

```
f[x_, y_] := L x y;
g[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2 - a;
res = Solve[
   D[f[x, y] + \[Lambda] g[x, y], {{x, y, \[Lambda]}}] == 0, {x, 
    y}, \[Lambda]] // Quiet
```

The answer itself looks like this:

```
{{x -> -(Sqrt[a]/Sqrt[2]), 
  y -> -(Sqrt[a]/Sqrt[2])}, {x -> -(Sqrt[a]/Sqrt[2]), 
  y -> Sqrt[a]/Sqrt[2]}, {x -> Sqrt[a]/Sqrt[2], 
  y -> -(Sqrt[a]/Sqrt[2])}, {x -> Sqrt[a]/Sqrt[2], 
  y -> Sqrt[a]/Sqrt[2]}}
```

I need the last pair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add those conditions in `Solve`, but you also need to specify eg that $a>0$:

```
Solve[{
   D[f[x, y] + λ g[x, y], {{x, y, λ}}] == 0,
   a > 0, x >= 0, y >= 0},
   {x, y}, λ
]
```

Answer (score 4):

There could be shorter way. How about

```
f[x_, y_] := L x y;
g[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2 - a;
res = SolveValues[D[f[x, y] + λ g[x, y], {{x, y, λ}}] == 0, {x, y}, λ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and now

```
p = Map[Assuming[a>0,Simplify[AllTrue[#,Positive]]]&,res]
Pick[res,p]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Can also use `Select`

```
Select[res,Assuming[a>0,Simplify[AllTrue[#,Positive]]]&]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You need to tell is that `a` is positive or not to be able to decide.